# how to fix 'DataFrame' object is not callable' error in python

Tags: python-3.6

i tried to use feature selection to verify my data, how should i editing these code? sss is my dataset

`sss = pd.read_excel("original dataset.xlsm")`

`x = sss()`

`df = pd.DataFrame(x.data, columns = x.feature_names)`

`df["SchoolSafety"] = x.target`

`X = df.drop("SchoolSafety",1)`

`y = df["SchoolSafety"]`

`df.head()`

i expect no error, but it shows TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable.

Comment: Can for you format your code please? And tell us the line number for the error?

Comment: it seems error comes from the second line.

Comment: May be try `x = pd.read_excel("original dataset.xlsm")` and skip the second line